# Minimum of inner products in unitary sphere

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, inner-products, maxima-minima

Let $A$ be a real $n\times m$ matrix and $x$ a real $m\times 1$ vector. Define the sphere 
$$
S^{n-1} = \{u\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|u\|_2=1\}.
$$
Is it true that 
$$
-\|Ax\|_2 = \min_{u\in S^{n-1}}u^{T}Ax\quad ? 
$$
This part of the next equality found in "High-dimensional statistics" by MJ Wainwright (p. 188):
$$
-\min_{v\in V}\|Ax\|_2 = \max_{v\in V}\{-\|Ax\|_2\}=\max_{v\in V}\min_{u\in S^{n-1}}u^{T}Ax.
$$
Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true.

By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality we get 
$$|u^TAx|=|\langle u, \, Ax\rangle|\le \|u\|\cdot \|Ax\|=\|Ax\|\,,$$
so $u^TAx\ge -\|Ax\|$ for every $u\in S^{n-1}$, 
and if $Ax\ne 0$, we reach $-\|Ax\|$ by setting $u=-\frac{Ax}{\|Ax\|}\in S^{n-1}$.